# Grab HTML of fourth TD in Jquery object

Tags: jquery

I have a table with the format:

```
   <tr>
    <td>001</td>
    <td>Value/td>
    <td>Value</td>
    <td>John Smith</td>
   </tr>
```

I have a variable pID that I want to compare against the first cell (ie - 001). I do that with the following:

```
  selectedTD = table
      .find('td')
      .filter(
        function() {
          return this.innerText === pID
        });
```

And this gives me the whole row as an object, now I only want to grab the HTML of the fourth TD (ie - John Smith).

Do I first convert selectedTD to a string and then use regex or can I store the value of the forth TD without having to do that?

I've tried using the selector td:nth-child(4) as a filter but I do not understand at what point I should use this.

Comment: try this .......find('td:eq(3)')

Comment: I don't think this works for me. I still need to find the td that matches my variable (in the example above that is the first cell). I then want to grab the value from the 4th cell of that row and store it as a variable.

Comment: this will definitely help .. please try and tell me the result...otherwise please put your full html and jquery here....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `:nth-child` selector to select nth element:

```
 $("td:nth-child(4)")
```

*note: nth-child selector has 1 based index.*

**Update**:

```
selectedfourthTD = table
  .find('td')
  .filter(
    function() {
      return this.innerText === pID
    }).eq(3);
```

Comment: Mate.. nth-child() has 1 based index. on the other hand :eq() has the 0 based index.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy:thanks... what i was thinking :/

Comment: @MilindAnantwar I still need to find the cell that matches my variable (in the example above, that is the first cell), how I do then select the 4th cell from that row?

Comment: @MilindAnantwar, if I change your value to eq(1) the logic works and I can get my pID, but if I change the values to 3 (or any other value other than 1) then I simply get "Undefined". I must be doing something incorrect.

Comment: @rlsaj:would be great if you share the fiddle.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar, I received the correct value by using:

contentOwner = selectedfourthTD.parent();
        contentOwner = contentOwner
          .find("td:nth-child(4)").html(); I am not sure if it is the cleanest way to use this however I do get what I need at the moment.